# std::unique_ptr, custom deleter and type change

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I would like to use unique_ptr with my deleter. 
I would like my unique_ptr with my deleter to be fully compatible with unique_ptr with default deleter.

I did so:

```
template <typename T>
struct QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor :
        public std::default_delete<T>
{
    void operator()(T *p)
    {
        p->deleteLater();
    }
};

template <typename T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> qtMakeUniqueSpecial(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(
                new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor<T>());
}
```

This compiles, but does not work. My custom deleter ignored and default one used instead as if I did not specify it at all.

I need all of this to be possible to do things like that:

```
auto ptr1 = qtMakeUniqueSpecial<MyObject>();
std::unique_ptr<MyObject> ptr2;
ptr2 = std::move(ptr1);
```

Please note that now even ptr1.reset() will lead to calling the standard deleter, not my one.

Is it even possible?

Comment: But after the move then `ptr1` doesn't have a pointer to the data. Calling `reset` on `ptr1` after the move to "delete" it makes no sense. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also please tell us *how* you know your deleter doesn't get called but the default is.

Comment: No. All you are doing is slicing your fancy deleter back to `default_delete`.

Comment: Of course, I call reset before the move. The minimal example is in the question.

Comment: T.C. , so it is not possible to achieve my goal?

Comment: "how you know your deleter doesn't get called" - i commented deleteLater call. Destructor is still called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use

```
namespace std {
  template<typename T, typename Deleter = default_delete<T> >
  class unique_ptr;
}
```

which has a second template argument `Deleter`. Failing to specify that, it defaults to `std::default_delete<T>`. Your code

```
std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                   QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor<T>());
```

passes a `const std::default_delete<T>&` to the [constructor of `std::unique_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), because that's what the constructor expects. Upon destruction (or call to member `reset()`), this will be called.

Note that the behaviour of `std::shared_ptr` is different: there is no second template argument for the deleter, though a custom deleter may be provided at construction (this will need to be stored via type erasure, which is avoided with `std::unique_ptr`).

Answer (score 2):

You need specify `QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor` as the template argument; otherwise, `std::default_delete` will be used as the deleter, which is slicing-copied from `QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor`.

```
template <typename T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T, QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor<T>> qtMakeUniqueSpecial(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor<T>> (
                new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                QObjectDeleteLaterDeletor<T>());
}
```

Note that you declare `ptr2` as `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>`, then `ptr2` will destroy the pointer by `std::default_delete`. If you declare its type accord with `ptr1` like `auto ptr2 = std::move(ptr1);` then it'll be fine.

Comment: I would like my type to be std::unique_ptr<T> . Not unique_ptr<T, Deleter>.

Comment: It's possible with shared_ptr and seems it's impossible with unique_ptr.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev Then the answer is NO, with `std::unique_ptr`. `std::shared_ptr` is different, it doesn't take the type of deleter as the class template parameter, but the template parameter of the constructor, then it's more flexible.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev BTW, if you apply the [AAA style](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), it won't make trouble in real world, IMO.